# ThinkPad T410 works fine with 4Gb RAM, freezes with 8Gb

Tags: memory, freeze, thinkpad

I've a strange problem with my trusty T410 (2537-26G) which has been working great with the factory-standard 4Gb RAM stick in the machine's only slot. I've tried replacing the stick with various 8Gb sticks, but am getting consistent freezes no matter which brand etc. I am trying. I have gone through three different sticks now (all brand new, and from different brands and vendors over more than a year) and they all show the same behaviour:

- When I boot the machine and let it run, it freezes within a few minutes.
- When I boot the machine into a memory testing program, it will freeze within seconds.

Prior to freezing, I am able to verify that it does indeed report 8Gb of memory. I am 100% sure that the memory I have bought is correct in relation to clock speed, etc.

Putting in my old 4Gb stick immediately fixes all problems except my need for more memory. So I am wondering: could there be a hardware fault in the laptop itself? Might this be a known issue? I have been unable to dig up similar complaints on the 'net so that's why I now ask here. (Not that I think it's an OS issue, but I want to state that the behaviour is the same across three different Linux OS'es.)

[image: single slot machine]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new RAM must be unsuitable for the ThinkPad T410.

RAM selection is very touchy, as the RAM must obey very strict limitations
imposed by the motherboard, and in addition some specs are never published.

The Lenovo page of
[Detailed specifications - ThinkPad T410](https://support.lenovo.com/fr/en/solutions/pd006109)
says :

[image]

The specification of "1 GB, 2GB, or 4GB memory" is the most important,
as it seems to mean that the motherboard does not support *one RAM stick*
of more than 4 GB.

An important support for this understanding of the phrase comes from the
[Crucial analyzer](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Lenovo/thinkpad-t410-series),
which does not offer any 8GB stick for your computer.
The only 8GB combination it offers is the
[Crucial 8GB Kit (2 x 4GB) DDR3L-1600 SODIMM](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/thinkpad-t410-series/CT5311306),
which has two sticks of 4 GB.

Comment: I've spent so much time reading the specs oh-so-carefully (or so I thought), and had the understanding that 8Gb is the maximum. But then, how can they write that, when the single slot can only take up to 4Gb?

Comment: The specs say that you have two slots. Two 4GB sticks make together 8 GB.

Comment: Then I've no idea where that other slot is, and I thought I knew ThinkPads pretty well. I've added a photo to the post. And no, there's no secondary slot or on-board RAM underneath there.

Comment: See the video [Tutorial: How to Upgrade T410/T420/400 Thinkpad Laptop to 8GB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dhW1nmAwXo).

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to find a computer that will play that YouTube link. I'm getting errors everywhere.

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: Huh. Might have been related to that outage that people were talking about. It works now. **The 2nd slot is under the keyboard!** Who'da thunk?

Answer (score 1):

What you don't know is that Lenovo T410 has two slots, one  is beneath the keyboard while the other one is under the laptop I.e. When you turn the laptop upside down. So the solution to achieving either 6GB or 8GB is buying additional 4GB or 2GB RAM of the same specification of the on you have already installed on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I has 2 slots. Each nasting 2gb. When you swap one by 8gb it gives you 10gb when this model takes up to 8gb other wise it freez. I had the same problem. Serch YouTube "thinkpad t410 ram upgrade" there you find out about second slot under keyboard. Dont worry it easy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).